# Grid and bucketfill are just off center/ have offset

Tags: gimp, patterns, selections

When I apply a pattern with the render option or the bucketfill it doesn't completely fill the selection without being off center/ having a offset (I'm not good with GIMP terminology ☹️)

I DID NOT apply a pattern on a separate layer

[image]

I circled the parts of the pattern that are "off center"

edit: I decided that the easiest choice for fixing this was to erase the offset (which are apparently called "seams"), and then stretch the remaining tiles to fit the selection, and it looks pretty much like how I wanted it to look

[image]

Comment: I can't really tell what I'm seeing here. Can you provide a step-by-step description of how to reproduce this to arrive at the exact result as shown in your image?

Comment: Okay, so I made a imgur album going through steps on how I made the 2 things, and I hope it will be easier to understand https://imgur.com/a/InOI7AV

Comment: @tyler Still unclear. We don't know where is the selection when you bucket-fill with marble2. How did you "color the spaces" and what as you intent? What was the selection then? Can you show the whole image for the last step (we don't know where the small image extract fits in the big picture).

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that the pattern doesn't start in the corner of the selection? AFAIK it starts at 0,0 (top right corner of the **layer**), and the selection just masks the part that is kept. Same for the grid.

Comment: no I dont think it does